# Azure APIM Developer Portal - choose what revision of the API to explore

Tags: azure-api-management

Is there a possibility to choose what API revision to view from the Developer Portal?
I can manually insert `;rev2` into the URL in the Developer Portal for that goal, but didn't find any possibility to select the revision from the UI.
I tried to search documentations and other places but didn't find any useful information.
This is for the managed version of the Developer Portal.

Thank you.

Comment: Don't think it's possible as only one rev can be the current one.

Comment: What you are doing might be versioning Versions differentiate themselves through a version number (which is a string of any value you choose), and a versioning scheme (path, query string or header).

Answer (score 0):

For apim revision, it's designed for non-breaking API changes so that this api could be tested safely then change `current` to replace the old one. This means only the current revision is exposed to the developer portal for users except the api developers(only these people know the revision exsits).

So there's no option for selecting the revision from the UI, what we can do is `setting current` to choose a revision to show in the developer portal.

[image]

Comment: If I misunderstood in some place, pls point it out, thanks for your response in advance : )

Comment: OP is asking about revisions, not versions.

Comment: @BakedInhalf Oh, sorry for the mistake.

Comment: Hello and thank you for the answer. I understand how to make revision available in the Developer Portal by making it current. However, as you said, revisions are made for non-breaking changes. So if we develop a new feature to the API, why we can't give our 3rd party developers the opportunity to see what is coming out in the future through the Developer Portal before the revision is made as current. I found the only way to achieve this goal by creating manually a link to the API details page which will include eg. ;rev=2 in the url.

Comment: @Konsta I really agree with you, but as I can see that there's no tutorial on how to list all the revisions till now(At least, I haven't found such document) : ( And if you'd like to achieve it, maybe you can use version instead, all the version could be list in the developer portal.